# Fragments are not getting replaced in the main_activity()

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am trying to make navigation drawer using fragments using the reference link : https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

But the problem is when i tap on any of the item in navigation drawer it does not replace the corresponding fragment to the main activity layout.

Main activity snippet:

```
    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem)  {
    // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass;
    switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.nav_first_fragment:

            //fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
            fragment=new FirstFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
            break;

        case R.id.nav_second_fragment:
            //fragmentClass = SecondFragment.class;
            fragment=new SecondFragment();
            FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            tx.replace(R.id.flContent, Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, "com.example.FirstFragment"));
            tx.commit();
            break;

        default:
            fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
    }
```

activity_main layout:

```
<!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top -->
<include
layout="@layout/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



<!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/flContent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer that comes from the left -->
<!-- Note that `android:layout_gravity` needs to be set to 'start' -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/nvView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:background="@android:color/white"
app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

fragment one layout:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:text="Fragment 1"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#FF5722"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

frament one java:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState){
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container,false);
if(container==null){
Log.d("First","Null");
return view;
}Log.d("First"," Not Null");
return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this in switch

```
switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {

 case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new FirstFragment()).commit();
      break;

 case R.id.nav_second_fragment:
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new SecondFragment()).commit();
      break;

}
```

and make sure you give the correct IDs to the switch. And "container" is the ID for the layout of the activity_main.xml

just give the ID to main Layout like

```
android:id="@+id/container"
```

Comment: bro i tried your solution but it did not change the output. it is still the same fragment one layout is not getting replaced in the place of activity main's linear layout.

Comment: Also i added a text view in the linear layout which i want to replace it with the fragment. In the text view i just wrote this is main activity. After running the app when i clicked the navigation drawer items, "This is main activity" remained. so i guess the issue is fragments are not getting replaced only.

Comment: you have to make a frame layout in the main layout like this        <RelativeLayout ...........<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container"/></RelativeLayout> and it will do the job

Comment: Replace a FrameLayput instead of Linear Layout